# Python exception when installing docker-compose

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, pip, docker

I have tried installing docker-compose on my jessie dist

```
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

However it encounters an exception

```
Downloading/unpacking docker-compose
  Downloading docker_compose-1.24.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (134kB): 134kB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six<2,>=1.3.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from docker-compose)
Downloading/unpacking cached-property<2,>=1.2.0 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading cached_property-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking docopt<0.7,>=0.6.1 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-b57ky9od/docopt/setup.py) egg_info for package docopt
Downloading/unpacking PyYAML<4.3,>=3.10 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading PyYAML-3.13.tar.gz (270kB): 270kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-b57ky9od/PyYAML/setup.py) egg_info for package PyYAML
Downloading/unpacking backports.ssl-match-hostname>=3.5; python_version < "3.5" (from docker-compose)
  Downloading backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.7.0.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-b57ky9od/backports.ssl-match-hostname/setup.py) egg_info for package backports.ssl-match-hostname
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests!=2.11.0,!=2.12.2,!=2.18.0,<2.21,>=2.6.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from docker-compose)
Downloading/unpacking websocket-client<1.0,>=0.32.0 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading websocket_client-0.56.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (200kB): 200kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking jsonschema<3,>=2.5.1 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking texttable<0.10,>=0.9.0 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading texttable-0.9.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-b57ky9od/texttable/setup.py) egg_info for package texttable
Downloading/unpacking docker[ssh]<4.0,>=3.7.0 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading docker-3.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (134kB): 134kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking dockerpty<0.5,>=0.4.1 (from docker-compose)
  Downloading dockerpty-0.4.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-b57ky9od/dockerpty/setup.py) egg_info for package dockerpty
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): urllib3==1.16 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from requests!=2.11.0,!=2.12.2,!=2.18.0,<2.21,>=2.6.1->docker-compose)
Downloading/unpacking docker-pycreds>=0.4.0 (from docker[ssh]<4.0,>=3.7.0->docker-compose)
  Downloading docker_pycreds-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1091, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.check_if_exists()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 811, in check_if_exists
    self.satisfied_by = pkg_resources.get_distribution(self.req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 553, in get_distribution
    dist = get_provider(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 427, in get_provider
    return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

But it didn't help

Comment: Have you already installed docker before trying to install docker-compose? Edit: You may have better luck asking about this on server fault as this looks more like a generic docker question than something Raspberry Pi specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `docker-compose` in the `apt` repository (at least for Buster) which would be preferable to pip, but Jessie is obsolete and unsupported so who knows.